# CSS generated icons vs Images

Tags: css, image

Will an imageless design (using CSS to generate icons) load faster than a traditional image based design?

NOTE: I completely understand the flexibility of being able to change an icon's colour, size etc. will a few changes to the CSS file is much more efficient, but I am unsure about the loading time.

Background:
I am looking into completing a project for a client that is an imageless design using CSS to generate the page icons, which was a project requirement to decrease loading time on mobile devices.  Normally, I would just slice out the icons in an image sprite and not worry about the load time seeing the browser would only have to load and cache on image.

Thanks!

Comment: Really not enough information to say. Would the CSS icons require loading fonts? Would the extra CSS bump the styles over the 25K cache limit for iOS? Would you be using sprites if you used images?  I think you'd have to test with your particular assets.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if site icons can be generated entirely in (relatively efficient) CSS, this will load faster than images. The rub is that most icons are far too complex to be generated using CSS, and the CSS might in some edge cases become so complex that the maintenance issues associated with maintaining complex code across browsers might outweigh the benefits. But in general, if you can do it in CSS without having to bend over backwards, it would be optimisation—and in the scenario you describe might well be *worthwhile* optimisation.

Comment: The OP may be talking about using @font-face for icon based typefaces?

Comment: Well, they *might* be... but if they are, they don't say so. The post says, "Using CSS to *generate* icons"... :)

Comment: And you’d think that @font-face wouldn’t offer much benefit over an icon sprite: either way, you’re downloading one file that contains all your icons. Depending on the icons, a font file might not be much smaller than an image file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the question is whether or not it's faster, but whether or not it's a good idea at all. I wouldn't sacrifice the flexibility of using images by making everything into pure CSS. You guarantee cross-browser compatibility with images, something that CSS3 cannot. Plus images are easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Think it in this way .. the size of css icon(the size of the code required to produce an icon) is an advantage and the other major advantage is the server hits. for ever image icon there is a hit which means there is a waiting time, downloading time, and rendering time, though its only in milliseconds the waiting time and downloading time are directly proportional to your server load.

In that case a css3 icon will not only save time and band-width but also reduce your server hits as the css file downloads only once and its contains all the style declarations for the entire site.

The advantages are enormous to choose a css icon. But there are some cases where a css icon is not suffecient, so its up to the developer to choose from a css icon or an image based on the requirements.

Comment: Clearly the person asking the question was *not* wondering what a CSS icon is. Your link to your own site was not necessary, and further, you did not disclose that it was a link to your own website.